# Do equations that rely on a fractional number of variables exist?

Tags: functions, soft-question

In statistics, data is usually fitted with trend lines. Usually you can get statistics back that say things pertaining to how correlated one variable is with another. For instance if a variable $x$ has 90% correlation with another variable $y$, you'd say that 90% of $y$'s value can be explained with $x$ and that 10% can't.

However I've never encountered equations that rely on fractional numbers of variables, but it seems like it would be a useful feature. For instance, define a function to be reliant on 1 and 1/2 variables. I'd propose that this set up work as follows. The first variable $u$ will always be affecting the function value $f$. However, the second variable $v$ will only affect $f$ *half* the time. This seems to be quite similar to how in statistics $y$ can be correlated with $x$ 90% of the time.

**Question:** Has anyone heard of this concept before? (It doesn't have to be exactly like the form above) I'd also like some references to materials to read about this. Also I should mention I'm more interested in the functional part of this concept than any of the linkings with statistics or otherwise. Having said that, possible applications are appreciated.

**Motivation:** Coordinate Systems in fractional dimensions are basically non-existent, maybe developing equations that can rely on fractional numbers of variables would change all that. So any references having to with that are also appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean half the time? With probability $\frac 1 2$?

Comment: @GFauxPas yes. And it could be any probability. For instance a function that relies on 1 and a 1/3 variables would have a variable that is present $1/3$ of the time.

Comment: Statistical correlation has nothing to do with the number of variables in an equation. If a variable is not viable for part of some expression, we express exactly why that is the case in mathematical terms for that variable. The number of variables in mathematical expressions is a discrete value on purpose, and if you run into situations where this doesn't seem to be the case, you either don't understand the purpose of variables or you don't understand the problem enough to express it with any mathematical completeness.

Comment: @Adam The statistical correlation was only an analogy. To address your second point. I believe those two counters are called ad hominem and glittering generalization. As a counter example, consider fractals. These objects have fractional dimensions. In fact it seems natural to say these objects have a fractional coordinate system, and the reason they are so hard to describe is precisely because we don't have a way to have fractional numbers of variables in our functions. Since one variable can make a line, two can make a square, it seems *logical* to say 1.26.. can make a Koch curve.

Answer (score 0):

Define a random variable that has some value $p$ of the time and is equal to zero $1-p$ of the time.

So you can say for example $F(u,v) = \sin u + X = \begin{cases}{ \sin u + f(v) : p = 1/2 \\\sin u + 0: p = 1/2}\end{cases}$

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I decided upon. The only problem I have with it, is that it ends up making extremely discontinuous functions. Of course, considering that the most pathological of functions are actually fractals, case in point the weierstrass function, maybe this is a step in the right direction? What do you think?

Comment: A decent attempt, but this is still making use of a full variance

Comment: @Adam And why is that bad?

Comment: Sorry, typo (*variable). The op asked for an example of an equation in which there is a non-integer number of variables. They are already aware of random variables, or at least similar concepts. What they are asking is, is it possible to have 1.789 variables in an equation. In other words, you have x, but you only have the first third of y and the other two thirds are simply not expressed.

Comment: @Adam I am Op and in your comment you said that "you'd only have the first third of y and the other two thirds are simply not expressed". In your example however, you suggest 1.789 variable equations. So in fact you'd have an x variable and 78.9% of a another variable, theoretically. Also, your right, I find this solution to be missing something, I just can't put my finger on it.