# Is there such a thing as 2.3 variables?

Tags: soft-question, definition, fractional-calculus

Is there such a thing as 2.3 variables? for example there are system of equations of n variables, but what about when n is not an integer , when n is a real number or even complex number? What about matrix?

Is there anything in math that generalises the  notion of variable? or even defines it?

I have known about fractional calculus for 25 years, but never came across the topic of generalisation of number variables.

I really want to tag this question "What am I looking for"

Comment: A *variable* is a symbol in a math expression. "Usually", expressions are strings of symbols of *finite* lenght, and every symbol is an individual "object". To say that we can write e.g. $2/3$-rd of a symbol makes little sense...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : same argument can be used for integration and differentiation, but there is such a thing as 2/3rd differential or integral..

Comment: "...there is such a thing as 2/3rd differential or integral". Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Paul : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: Take a point from a square; that's two variables. Take a point from a set with Hausdorff dimension 2.3, and that would be 2.3 variables (in some sense). This is not a very enticing opportunity, though. Also, it is hardly related to fractional calculus.

Comment: @Arjang: Functional calculus for differential/integral operators makes sense but citing this as the "same argument" used by Mauro has no logic.

Comment: @Paul : remember back the time when you struggled to learn differentiation, now the idea of differentiation to a complex order is trivial to you, back at the begining it would have been absurd. Now imagine yourself sometime in future that have no problem manipulating generalised structure that reduces to what we call variables for integers. Do you think sum of angles of a triangle can be more than 180 degrees? what about less? I dont need hand waving logic for what does not make sense, prove it with math if you can.

Comment: Closely related:  [Do equations that rely on a fractional number of variables exist?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233155/do-equations-that-rely-on-a-fractional-number-of-variables-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is everything in "soft questions".  Sticking to a context of formal languages, no, there is not a possibility of "a system of equations in $n$ variables... when $n$ is not an integer".  For the sake of having validity of formulas be effectively decidable, formal languages are limited to finite strings drawn from "alphabets" of distinct symbols.  Therefore in this context, a non-whole number of variables cannot be realized.

However if we are *trying* to think outside the box, then one possible tack is the notion of [fractional degrees of freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124961/reporting-degrees-of-freedom-for-welch-t-test) as discussed over at Cross Validated (Stats.SE).  The connection is fairly straightforward:  In statistical estimation the notion of [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) typically corresponds to the number of independent *parameters* available in optimizing a fit.  For example, the *sample mean* (as an estimator of the population mean) using $N$ points has $N-1$ degree of freedom (because samples sharing a common mean are constrained by that one degree).

Formulas involving a [degrees-of-freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) value are important in computing [confidence intervals](http://tf.nist.gov/phase/Properties/five.htm) and thus in justifying tests of significance.  In some cases, such as variance of non-chi-square distributions, the appropriate "degrees of freedom" value is not an integer.

This suggests an analogy to the context suggested in Comments above, by @Ivan, for topologies with fractional dimensions, e.g. with sampling in a space where "fractional" numbers of coordinates are needed to specify a point. In both cases it might be objected that we are taking liberties with terminology to make a connection with the number of variables in a system of equations.  However the same can be said about the number of derivatives taken and the fractional calculus.